# Excel Power Query

Tags: excel

So I have a weird problem. On my workstation, the version of Office is 2013. I am trying to connect to a JIRA cloud server via Excel to fetch records from JIRA into a spreadsheet [see article here ... https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Fetch-data-from-JIRA-to-excel/qaq-p/198786]. My Excel does not show Power Query option on the ribbon and I tried to add the dll from "Add-Ins" option but to no avail. So, is there a way I could connect to an external server and cache the credentials?

Comment: So you tried to actually download the add-in? For excel 2013 you would still need to install PQ

Comment: I have not yet. I do not have admin privileges on my workstation. So, I am trying to get it installed via helpdesk. However, if I approach this issue thru code/macro and I use this: ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=), do I still need Power Query installed?